# Center a button widget in a column using tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter, widget

I have a Labelframe and inside that LabelFrame, I've placed a button. That button will always appear in the top-left corner of the LabelFrame, though I would like it to center itself within the LabelFrame. What property am I missing that will force this button to center itself inside of the LabelFrame?

```
self.f1_section_frame=LabelFrame(self.mass_window, text="LOCATIONS", width=300, height=998, padx=5, pady=5, bd=5)
self.f1_section_frame.grid(row=0, rowspan=6, column=1, sticky="nw", padx=(2,0))
self.f1_section_frame.grid_propagate(False)

self.button_frame1 = LabelFrame(self.f1_section_frame, width=275, height=50)
self.button_frame1.grid_propagate(False)
self.button_frame1.grid(row=1, column=0)
self.b1_scoring=Button(self.button_frame1, text="CONFIRM\nLOCATION(S)", height=2, width=10, command=self.initiate_site_scoring, justify="center")
self.b1_scoring.grid(row=0,column=0, pady=(1,0))
```

Comment: leaving out pady should - per [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/grid.html) center the widget inside the parent. It will nevertheless only center it inside the row/col. depending on their size it will appear centered or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the response @R4PH43L. I gave that a shot and it didn't seem to change. However, it got me thinking so I removed "grid_propagate" from the frame that encloses my buttons, which then wrapped the frame around the buttons without any space and centered the frame within the column in which IT was placed. Then I used padx=(x,0) on my leftmost button and padx=(0,x) on my rightmost button to add the space needed on the left and right side and it's working how I need it to now.

```
self.f1_section_frame=LabelFrame(self.mass_window, text="LOCATIONS", width=300, 
height=998, padx=5, pady=5, bd=5)

self.f1_section_frame.grid(row=0, rowspan=6, column=1, sticky="nw", padx=(2,0))
self.f1_section_frame.grid_propagate(False)

self.button_frame1 = LabelFrame(self.f1_section_frame, width=275, height=50)
self.button_frame1.grid(row=1, column=0)

self.b1_scoring=Button(self.button_frame1, text="CONFIRM\nLOCATION(S)", height=2, width=10, 
command=self.initiate_site_scoring, justify="center")

self.b1_scoring.grid(row=0,column=0, padx=(15,0))

self.b2_scoring=Button(self.button_frame1, text="CLEAR\nSELECTION(S)", height=2, 
width=10, command=self.clear_selected_locations)

self.b2_scoring.grid(row=0,column=1)

self.b3_scoring=Button(self.button_frame1, text="UPDATE\nSELECTION(S)", height=2, width=10, 
command=self.update_selected_location_details)

self.b3_scoring.grid(row=0,column=2, padx=(0,15))
```